# Why does my script not take command arguments?

Tags: bash, command, arguments

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

function usage() {
    cat << EOF >&2
Usage: $0 [-h] [-rs <start_num>] [-re <end_num>]

-h:  help: displays list of options for command $0
-rs<int>: range start: should be the number to go from - the lower of the two ranges. <int>
-re<int>: range end: should be the number to add up to - the highest of the two ranges. <int>
EOF
    exit 1
}

function addition() {
    sum=0

    for number in "$@"; do
        sum=$(( sum + number))
    done

    # set defaults    
    rangeStart=0
    rangeEnd=0
    error=false

    # loop arguments
    OPTIND=1

    while getopts rs:re:h: o; do
        case $o in
            rs) rangeStart=$OPTARG;;
            re) rangeEnd=$OPTARG;;
            h) usage;;
            *) error=true;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))

    echo $rangeStart
    echo $rangeEnd

    if [ "$error" = true ] ; then
        echo 'Invalid argument passed. See addition -h for usage.'
    else
        echo 'Total: '$sum
    fi
}
```

At the moment, I'm just trying to add command arguments so user can type:

```
$ addition -rs 4 -re 10
```

and it loops from 4 up to 10 (so adding `4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10`) and outputs that total.

but doing the above returns output of:

> 0 
>   0 
>   Invalid argument passed. See addition -h for usage.

so it's not recognising my params. And when I alter the command to:

```
$ addition -rs4 -re10
```

it outputs the same.. what am I doing wrong in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getopts` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts) can only handle single-character options; you have to use something like

```
getopts 's:e:h'
```

I've also dropped the colon after `h`, as you probably don't want an argument for `-h`.

Comment: I did want an argument for -h to be --help - ok so I changed to `s:e` and that does work. Wasn't aware it doesn't support more than one char per option. Ok so how do I make it so it's `--range-start=` ?

Comment: [This article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing) talks about long options.

Comment: After checking out the article I've got my script working with the --long-option :) thank you :) - as this directly answers my question, will accept :)